# Java increment logical problem (increment in conditional statements)

Tags: java, conditional-statements, increment

I have this assessment that is given to me, but this two questions stuck in my mind. These two codes seem similar but is giving of different output based on the increment

Code #1:

```
package com.company;
class Main {
public static void main(String [] args) {
                boolean x = true;
                boolean y = false;
                short z = 42;

                if((z++ == 42) && (y = true))
                    z++;
                if((x = false) || (++z == 45))
                    z++;
                System.out.println("z = " + z);
                }
}
```

This code seemed fine it increments the value that it should be increment and returning that value to "z" thus the output

Output:

```
z = 46

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But the second code seemed different as it does not save the incremented value

Code #2:
package com.company;

public class Test2

```
{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        boolean x = true;
        boolean y = false;
        short z = 42;
        if((x == true) && (y = true))
            z++;
        if((y == true) || (++z == 44))
            z++;
        System.out.println("z = " + z);
    }
}
```

This one does not save the increment on the second if conditional statement like the first code

Output:

```
z = 44

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Am I missing something important?

Comment: Are you missing something important? Yes, don't write confusing and difficult code like that.

Comment: In the first one, the final `z++` isn't inside the conditional. (Most) whitespace has no semantic meaning in Java, unlike, say, Python.

Comment: It's my instructor is the one that wrote the code. i'm trying to understand the output and why is it like that

Comment: Andy sorry my fault. i'm the one that put the system out below the final if statement for me to understand even if i remove that system out it's still the same output which is 46

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the logical OR operator (`||`) is *short-circuiting*: if the first condition is known to be true, then the second condition **is not executed at all**.

That means the `z++` in `(++z == 44)` is not executed, hence the end result is 44 instead of 45.

As mentioned in the comments, the *bitwise* OR operator (`|`) is not short-circuiting, so both statements are always executed.

---

*Code like this can be very confusing. Code should be primarily readable. Never use an assignment within a condition. `b = false` can be easily confused with `b == false`. Also avoid using increment operators in the middle of other operations, only as standalone expressions.*

Comment: @TenebrisMortem You can use the bitwise operator `|` (single pipe) if you don't want short-circuit behavior.